# Recursive algorithm for Budgeted Itinerary

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to solve a recursive problem. However, failing to come up with a working solution. When working with recursive problems I usually start by making an iterative one then converting it, but in this case, I was not able to do so...

The input is a list of n items given by their unit prices from least to most expensive, and a budget value; all positive integers.

```
method(int unitPriceList[], int budget )
Unit Price List = [ 3 , 7 , 9 ]. Budget = 18
```

The output prints all possible saturated itineraries as a list of item quantities, one list per line, each followed by its total price on the same line. The term saturated means that it is within budget, but it will fail to be within budget if we add any more item to it.

```
Quantities = [ 0 , 0 , 2 ]. Total Price = 18.
Quantities = [ 1 , 2 , 0 ]. Total Price = 17.
Quantities = [ 0 , 1 , 1 ]. Total Price = 16.
...
The number of saturated itineraries = …
```

I would be really appreciative if you could point me in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: your comment on my answer says that you're still stuck.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "wasn't able to find a way" isn't a problem specification for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a case of the "all combinations of coins" problem.  Find a solution for that.  To convert to your case, add a unit coin (Price == 1).  Now, reject any solution that has as many unit coins as your cheapest price (3 in this case).

Restating, you're looking for a count of the ways you can make 18 cents with coin denominations of (1, 3, 7, 9)  -- but you can't use more than two 1-cent coins.  That would require trading in those coins for a higher denomination.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: I was able to determine the number of saturated itineraries. However, wasn't able to find a way to output it to the user like it was specified above.